# Creating a one column table in matlab using a 1D array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to save a 1D array into a table in MATLAB. I would like the data to be saved in one column, with 5 rows of data, not 5 columns with one row of data (shown below).

`testarray = [1:5];`

`testarray =`

```
 1     2     3     4     5
```

`t=table(testarray);`

`t=array2table(testarray)`

`t =`

```
testarray1    testarray2    testarray3    testarray4    testarray5
__________    __________    __________    __________    __________

1             2             3             4             5
```

What I would like the output to look like:

`t =`

```
testarray
_________
1 
2 
3 
4 
5
```

If anyone has any idea of how I can make this work, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB's [`table` objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) are row-oriented, and MATLAB makes no assumptions about the shape of your data for the ambiguous vector case.

Because `[1:5]` is a row vector:

```
>> [1:5]

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5
```

MATLAB will treat this as one row of data.

Because you want column-oriented data, you will need to [transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) this vector:

```
>> [1:5].'

ans =

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
```

In order for MATLAB to treat it as a single variable (column):

```
>> testarray = [1:5];
t = table(testarray.')

t = 

    Var1
    ____

    1   
    2   
    3   
    4   
    5
```